# Is there any way to mock a variable inside a function?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, nock

The code works like this

```
let getToken = await apiCall();
```

`apiCall()` calls a few internal functions and populates `getToken` variable with a token.  The problem is, in my tests, I can't seem to populate that variable with anything.  It is always undefined and an error gets thrown. Is there any way to populate this variable with a dummy value in a unit test?

EDIT

```
constructor() {
        this._token = '';
}
```

I want to inject a value in token via a unit test. I'm trying to use `sinon` right now.

Comment: Please provide more code to clearify your question.

Comment: You should mock `apiCall` to return some test value and that all you need.

Comment: I'm tried mocking the call to return what I'd normally expect, no luck.

Comment: I edited a little above.  I basically want to populate the value of a constructor in my unit test.  Is this possible with Sinon? @slideshowp2